# Uniform Boundedness for Non Linear Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Is there a non linear version for the Uniform Boundedness Theorem for linear operators? I would appreciate some well explained references

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the most general space on which Banach-Steinhaus (Uniform Boundedness Principle) holds is a barrelled space. This may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrelled_space.

Comment: I was looking for something more specific, like if the family of operators $T_n$ have a given property or so.